# How does Improved Moogle Throw work?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

The in-game text seems to suggest that I can just throw Mog wherever, and sometimes he'll bring me back useful stuff.  I've tried it a few times (mostly on accident) and have gotten things like 1 gil.  Is it just a random chance to get something rare?  Does the world I'm in at the time or anything else have an impact on what I get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be fairly honest, the Improved Moogle Throw is practically useless minus a couple of key locations where throwing him would be worth while. I can only remember a couple of good places, and here they are in case you haven't found them already.

If you go in to Academia 4XX AF, you can throw Mog in to the holographic globe in the center of the Academy Headquarters where Hope is located, therefore rewarding you with a Silver Chocobo.

The last one I can remember is in the Archylte Steppes. If you head to the edge of the Marshland where it drops in to a sort of canyon, there should be a little ledge down below at a certain spot where you can throw Mog for a Wild Artefact.

Sorry if I couldn't have been of anymore help to you, but this is pretty much all I can give. :)

Comment: If I remember correctly, the Silver Chocobo should be excellent with the races in Serendipity. I remember using it for a solid amount of time until coming across the Gold one in the Dying World. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time you will get useless stuff but in certain area's you can get monster crystals or monster decorations. Although sometimes the chances for this are very low.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "in certain areas"?  Do I just have to be in the right part of the timeline?  Or is it more like "stand in this area of the map and throw Mog at X"?  If the latter, is there any sort of pattern to the areas (like throwing Mog past the edge of where I can move)?

Comment: he means as in correct time and place, still most of it is random so he probably can't explain it.

Comment: Bwarner wish i could help you with the locations but i only came across a few myself. But sometimes its just the map you are in and sometimes its a specific place and time for example the red flowers near the first cactuar statue on the archlyte steppe